# How to access elements of a Javascript array using Template Strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, template-strings

I have a Javascript Array whose value I need to access in a Template String, how can I do that?

I have something like this,

```
//an array named link globally defined
function formatter(row,value){
    return `<a href = $link[$row]>Abc</a>`;
}
```

Comment: Please post JavaScript code as per [mcve]

Comment: Please post related information along with question, it's quite unclear

Comment: Suppose I have an Array named Arr, how can I use elements in that, while in a Template String, something like this - `$Arr[$i]`. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are plainly asking about 'Accessing an array value inside a template string', then:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3]

console.log(`${arr[0]}`) // 0
```

If you want to have an index as a variable, then you go

```
const arr = [1,2,3]
const index = 0
console.log(`${arr[index]}`) // 1
```

And to answer your code:

```js
const link = [1,2,3]

function formatter(row,value){
    return `<a href = ${link[row]}>Abc</a>`;
}
```

would just work.

for example

```
formatter(0) // "<a href = 1>Abc</a>"
```

Comment: How about I want to acccess it with variable i instead of 0

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please have a look. Basically everything inside the `${}` work as a plain javascript expression.